# Could I get the complete path with the variables of '__filename' on the Windows os?

Tags: node.js

I've created a project, `vscode-extension`, but I'm having troubles while debugging. I have the the string of `/index.js` but not the complete path string like `c:/xx/xx/index.js` with the global variables of `__filename` or `__dirname`. How could I get the complete path in nodejs?

[This is the project](https://github.com/pikadun/npm-package-manage)

```
OS:Windows 10
Nodejs:v10.13.0
vscode:1.33.1
```

```
console.log(__filename); // /index.js
console.log(__dirname); // /
console.log(process.cwd()); // c:/User/wg/xxx/index.js
```

I expect get the complete path like

```
c:/User/wg/xxx/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd resloved the problem by modified `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  node:false
};
```

I used the `webpack` in my project,`webpack` would to polyfill or mock certain Node.js globals.
These are the defaults:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  node: {
    console: false,
    global: true,
    process: true,
    __filename: 'mock',
    __dirname: 'mock',
    Buffer: true,
    setImmediate: true

    // See "Other node core libraries" for additional options.
  }
};
```